# Ocaml Tree. I have this part of code: [(aux (c+1) l)@(aux (c+1) r) ]

Tags: ocaml

Can someone tell me what does this code do in my program please?
 (aux (c+1) l)@(aux (c+1) r)

Here is all the code :

```
 let rec aux c = function
   Empty -> []
    |Tr(x,l,r) ->
     let l =
      (aux (c+1) l)@(aux (c+1) r) in
       if c = n then x::l else l
         in aux 1 tr;;
```

Answer (score 2):

You've left out some context that defines `n` and `tr`. I would also say that your question is quite vague. Generally speaking, the expression you mention gets lists of values from further down the tree. It concenates the two lists with the `@` operator.

Comment: yes, it's true here is the code: type ’a tree = Empty |
Tr of ’a * ’a tree * ’a tree;;
let f n tr =
let rec aux c = function
Empty -> []
|Tr(x,l,r) ->
let l =
(aux (c+1) l)@(aux (c+1) r) in
if c = n then x::l else l
in aux 1 tr;;